# Using @mediascreen to center my promoslider pluggin

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress promoslider pluggin on the front of my website which is inside it's own div, the css looks like this:

```
#content.promoslider {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 16%;
 height: 420px;
 width: 840px;
 background-color: #3397cc;
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 35px;
 border: none;
 }
```

On my laptop it is centred and looks fine but on different sized monitors (mainly wider ones) it isn't in the center. You can see it on my website's homepage http://designbyiliria.com/

Could some one please tell me how I can use @mediascreen to adjust the margin-left depending on which monitor it is viewed on I'm a bit confused.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the margins to auto if you want it to be centered on varying resolutions.

```
#content.promoslider {
 height: 420px;
 width: 840px;
 background-color: #3397cc;
 margin: 20px auto 35px auto;
 border: none;
 }
```